# ExpressJS + Express-mailer No default engine

Tags: node.js, express

I've developed my web app using ReactJS and I'm using as a server ExpressJS. Everithing was working fine until I implemented a /contactme endpoint which just must work as restful POST to send an email. I mean, my aim is just publishing an endpoint to send mails.

I'm using express-mailer for the job, but when I try to send an email using send method I'm getting this error:

> message:"No default engine was specified and no extension was provided."
>   stack:"Error: No default engine was specified and no extension was provided.\n    at new View (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:62:11)\n    at EventEmitter.render (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:569:12)\n    at sendMail (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express-mailer\lib\express-mailer.js:55:5)\n    at Object.exports.extend.createSend [as send] (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express-mailer\lib\express-mailer.js:98:7)\n    at c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\server.js:28:16\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n    at next (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)\n    at Route.dispatch (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\React\web.facundolarocca.com\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)\n    at c:\React\web....

I understand that ExpressJS needs some view engine to return html files, but in my case I'm going to respond a simpli JSON.

Below is my code:

```c#
var path = require('path');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var mailer = require('express-mailer');
var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/build')));

mailer.extend(app, {
  from: 'no-reply@gmail.com',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  secureConnection: true,
  port: 465,
  transportMethod: 'SMTP',
  auth: {
    user: '*********@gmail.com',
    pass: '**********'
  }
});

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  //this is working fine
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/build/index.html')
});

app.get('/contactme', function (req, res) {
  try {
    app.mailer.send('test', {
      to: 'myemaila@myemail.com.ar',
      subject: 'some subject'
    }, function (err) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(400).json('There was an error sending the email');
      } else {
        res.status(200).json('Email Sent');
      }
    });
  } catch (error) {
    //Error is raised here
    res.status(500).json(error);
  }
});

app.listen(PORT, function (error) {
  if (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } else {
    console.info("==>   Listening on port %s. Visit http://localhost:%s/ in your browser.", PORT, PORT);
  }
});
```

So I have two problems, on one hand is **how to avoid this error** , but in the other hand is **why do I need an egine view** .

I just expect, from the client side, to read the status code to show some message. I thought I could be able to implement in the same way as I was using restify.

Comment: The view engine is needed for rendering of the email html that you want to send. To avoid the error read the documentation https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-mailer#views or don't use express-mailer and use something else that doesn't reguire view engine.

Comment: Probably I need to use something like nodemailer instead. After too much reading I was suspecting what you have answered me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to move to `nodemailer`. Here is the whole code:

### package.json

```json
{
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "nodemailer": "^2.7.0",
    "nodemailer-smtp-transport": "^2.7.2"
  }
}
```

### Code

```js
server.post('/contactme', (req, res) => {    
  try{
    let mailer = require('nodemailer')
    let smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport')

    let options = {
      service: config.mailService.service,
      secure: true,
      auth: {
        user: config.mailService.user,
        pass: config.mailService.password
      }
    }

    let transport = mailer.createTransport(smtpTransport(options))

    let mail = {
      from: 'from',
      to: 'to',
      subject: 'subject',
      html: 'body'
    }

    transport.sendMail(mail, (error, response) => {
      transport.close()
      if (error) {
        res.json(400, {error});
      } else {
        res.json(200, {response: 'Mail sent.'});
      }
    })
  } catch(error) {
    res.json(400, {error});
  }
})
```